# Change column and row using SAS

Tags: sas

My data set is: 

`|ID  | SNP | GEN |
|:--:|:---:|:---:|
|1   | A   | AG  | 
|2   | A   | GG  |
|3   | A   | AG  |
|4   | A   | AG  |`

I need to do this:

`|SNP | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 |
|:---|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|
|A   | AG  | GG  | AG  | AG  |`

I've tried to use the following command, but it did not work:

`proc transpose data=data1; run;`

Someone knows how to make this using SAS?

Comment: This is know as transposing your data, look at PROC TRANSPOSE. This question, as phrased does not meet SO rules. Please post what you've tried so far and what's not working. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: SO guidelines to help ask better questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See, for example, https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/how-to-reshape-data-long-to-wide-using-proc-transpose/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add more options to your PROC TRANPOSE call to get it to do what you want.

```
proc transpose data=data1 out=WANT prefix=ID ;
  by SNP;
  id ID;
  var GEN;
run;
```

The BY statement will process each value of SNP as a separate set to transpose. Make sure data is sorted by SNP if there are more values than in your example. The ID statement tells it which variable to use to generate the new variable name. The VAR statement tells it which variable to transpose, to transpose character variables you must use a VAR statement. The PREFIX= option lets you specify characters to use as prefix for the generated variable names.